# Пропали логотип, иконки

Tags: дефект

Зашел на сайт и вижу, что пропали все изображения, стрелки в вопросах, логотип.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновлял страницу много раз, ничего. В чем проблема?

P.S. Как указал Grundy, я проверил, стили logo, там такое:

```
#hlogo a {
   top: 5px;
   background-image: url("img/sprites.png?v=437815a0d7e1");
   background-image: url("img/sprites.svg?v=9e528d73f9d4"),none;
   background-position: top left;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Ошибка в этой строке - `background-image: url("img/sprites.svg?v=9e528d73f9d4"),none;`, если ее убрать, то логотип отображается. Во всех местах, где не отображаются иконки и логотипы, не грузит `svg`, с `png` проблем нет.

**UPDATE** Если перейти по такому адресу `img/sprites.svg?v=9e528d73f9d4`, то появляется это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Браузер - Яндекс.Браузер версии 16.7.1.20936 под Windows.

Comment: Подскажите, проблема наблюдается со всеми сайтами сети или только со Stack Overflow на русском? Пробовали ли вы сбросить кэш и куки? Проявляется ли дефект во всех обозревателях или только в каком–то конкретном?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Сейчас проверил - это наблюдается в одном Яндекс.Браузере. Да, со всеми сайтами сети.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести лог консоли разработчика?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, могу, но он пустой

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, кэш и куки почистил, не работает

Comment: Возможно, в последнее время были установлены какие–либо расширения (плагины)?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, расширения и плагины вообще не устанавливаю. Самое интересное, в режиме инкогнито в Яндекс.Браузере все работает, а в обычном - нет.

Comment: Установил последнюю версию Яндекс Браузера (Version 16.7.0.3348 (64-bit)) для Mac OS. Ошибку воспроизвести не могу.

Comment: А у меня не последняя, надо обновить

Comment: Обновил до версии 16.7.1.20936 (Windows). Все равно сохраняется проблема, могу обзор запилить, чтоб подтвердить данный факт.

Comment: С большой вероятностью, ошибка именно на клиенте (то есть, у вас локально). К сожалению, обзор тут не поможет. При установке, заметил, что Яндекс Браузер использует общее с Google Chrome хранилище данных. Если у вас установлен Chrome, пожалуйста, попробуйте отчистить куки в нем.

Comment: Как ни странно, иногда, особенно с Windows, спасает перезагрузка ПК. Как говориться, «Семь проблем – один reboot».

Comment: Перезагрузил - не помогло. Ладно, как всегда потом само по себе исправится и все заработает.

Comment: Надо решить! Если вы предоставите больше информации, я передам все разработчикам. В текущем виде ошибку не воспроизвести, к сожалению.

Comment: Я готов предоставить информацию, скажите только какую.

Comment: @Артем, выдели в консоли разработчика логотип, посмотри какая картинка ему должна грузиться, что-то вроде: `#hlogo a {
    ...
    background-image: url("img/sprites.png?v=d870db018c41");...` и попробуй открыть этот адрес напрямую

Comment: @Grundy, я обновил вопрос

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я добавил в вопрос информацию о проблеме со стилями.

Comment: @Артем, а если напрямую открывать адрес с svg - Он открывается и показывается? или тоже ничего и никаких ошибок?

Comment: @Grundy, добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а вот это уже можно передавать разработчикам :-)

Comment: @Артем, можно наверное еще версию браузера добавить в вопрос

Comment: @Grundy, добавил)

Comment: @Артем Уточнил у ребят. Говорят, это место уже пол года как не трогали.

Comment: Хороший багрепорт получился, подробный. )

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, там в ошибке кстати даже конкретная строка указана, я мельком глянул по самой ошибке, возможно именно данный браузер так может реагировать например на какой-нибудь атрибут в svg

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну исправить то как-то надо, может быть не у меня одного присутствует данная проблема с отображением `svg`.

Comment: @Артем Что–то мне подсказывает, что дело в кэше Яднекс браузера. У меня в стилях следующие ссылки: [первая](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.svg?v=01c1db151660) и [вторая](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.svg?v=d870db018c41). Пожалуйста, попробуйте отчистить кэш. Более того, приведенная вами ссылка у меня прекрасно открывается в Яндекс Браузере.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, первая ссылка открывается с ошибкой, вторая нет. Кэш я вчера отчистил полностью и везде где только можно. Это не помогло.

Comment: @Артем  Пожалуйста, подскажите, получилось ли победить дефект?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, к сожалению, нет